# Проблема выхода из цикла

Tags: java

Программа с помощью бесконечного цикла должна суммировать числа, которые вводит пользователь. Она должна работать до тех пор, пока не будет введён 0.
Я дошел до следующего, больше не знаю что не так:

```
class Praktikum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0; // Сумма
        int input; // Ввод пользователя

        while (input != 0) {
            input = scanner.nextInt(); //сканирует ввод 
            sum = sum + input; // добавляет введенное
        }
        System.out.println("Сумма введённых чисел: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: int input = -1;

Comment: Виктор спасибо! очень оперативно! сильно выручили! Сейчас пойду разибраться почему именно "-1", а вам хорошего вечера/ночи.

Comment: значение должно быть проинициализировано чем-то отличным от нуля

Comment: понял, а если будет 0, то цикл сразу завершится, или даже не запустится

Comment: ага, завершится

Comment: какая именно ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно присваивать значение непосредственно в условии цикла `while`, это гарантирует, что переменной `input` *всегда* будет присвоено какое-либо значение.

Также можно добавить проверку на то, содержит ли сканируемый поток ввода целое число при помощи вызова `scanner.hasNextInt()` для защиты от ошибок ввода (тогда цикл завершится не только при вводе нуля, но и как только пользователь введёт нечисловое значение)

```java
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0; // Сумма
        int input; // Ввод пользователя

        while (scanner.hasNextInt() && (input = scanner.nextInt()) != 0) {
            sum += input; // добавляет введенное
        }
        System.out.println("Сумма введённых чисел: " + sum);
    }
```